# child directive access every parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do a `slider` in angularJS. I have a child directive with events listeners. When the main event (`mousedown`) is listened to, it calls a function from the parent directive (via a controller) and changes style of various html elements. Works like a charm when there is only one directive on the page. If there are more than one, every parent controller is called. 
I don't understand why.

Plknr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9vGXxjDbqqEOzLcXRkoW?p=preview

**Parent directive:**

```
return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            sliderStep: '@',
            sliderBothHandles: '@',
            sliderMinVal: '=', //value min handle
            sliderMaxVal: '=', //value max handle
            sliderMin: '@', //minimum value authorized
            sliderMax: '@' //maximum value authorized
        },
        templateUrl: 'slider_template',
        controller: sliderController,
        transclude: true

};
```

**Child directive:**

```
return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: link,
        require: '^mcsSlider',
        scope: true
};
```

**Markup:**

```
<mcs-slider slider-step="1" slider-max-val="formCtrl.value1" slider-min="0" slider-max="7200">
   <div mcs-slider-handle class="slider-handle max-slider-handle round" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="7200" aria-valuenow="{{formCtrl.value1}}" tabindex="0" style="left:0%;"></div>
</mcs-slider>
```

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the `$interval` inside the `mcsSliderHandle` directive.
Could `$('.min-slider-handle').css('left')` be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be inside the directive `mcsSliderHandle`, in the `$interval` function.
You're using `$('.min-slider-handle')` that will find all the elements with that class!
You have to retrieve only the elements inside the current directive.
Wrong but working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LcbamYGRyxv6cegI3rbp?p=preview)